# Is $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$ closed set

Tags: real-analysis

Is $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$ closed set? I don't get it how to show, when a set contains $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Any help appreciated.

Also, is $(-\infty,1]$ closed? Thanks.

Comment: It is closed iff the complement $(1,2)$ is open.

Comment: Since your set neither contains $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$, I don't understand where your problem lies.

Comment: ok, thanks. Since the complement is open...

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks, it was really easy. I just got confused and was trying to prove if $(-\infty, 1]$ and $(2,\infty]$ are separately closed. So, I could not do it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can how can I prove $(-\infty, 1]$ is closed. (because, that way I was doing, and this is where I got stuck!)

Comment: @user467365 Again, it's closed because its complement is an open set.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : ok, I think there is problem in my logic: I know that, if every sequence has a convergent subsequence, that set is closed (in $\mathbb{R}$). Now take, $x_n=1-n$, $x_n\in (-\infty,1]$, but limit is not, where is wrong here?

Comment: @user467365 You're wrong because the assertion “every sequence has a convergent subsequence” is independent of the fact that the set is closed. For instance, $(0,1)$ is not closed, but every sequence of elements of $(0,1)$ has a convergente subsequence. And, as you noticed, although $(-\infty,1]$ is closed, not every sequence of elements of that set has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks!

Comment: @user467365 if every sequence from some set $A$ in a metric space $X$ has a convergent subsequence to a point in $A$, then $A$ is closed. But it's not necessarily the other way. If a set is closed, then it's not certain that for any sequence in that set we can find a subsequence convergent to a point in that set

Comment: @Adam thanks! ${}$

Answer (score 2):

A set is closed if and only if its complement is open. The complement of $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$ is $(1,2)$ which is open (in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in $\mathbb{R^2}$) since each point of the segment $(1,2)$ is an interior point of $(1,2)$. 
$$$$Alternatively you could go by the definition of a closed set (ie a set which contains all of its limit points). Clearly all the limit points of $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$ are contained in $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$. Hence $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$ is closed.
$$$$To address whether $(-\infty,1]$ is closed:$$$$

Again there are two alternatives. One is by noting that once again the complement of $(-\infty,1]$ (ie $(1,\infty)$) is an open set (in $\mathbb{R}$) since all its points lie in the interior of $(1,\infty)$.

$$$$The second alternative is by checking if every limit point of $(-\infty,1]$ is contained within $(-\infty,1]$ or not. Note that a limit point $p$ of a set $E$ is defined as a point such that $every$ neighborhood of $p$ contains another point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in E$. Clearly all the limits points of $(-\infty,1]$ are the points $p\in (-\infty,1]$. Thus every limit point of $(-\infty,1]$ is contained in $(-\infty,1]$, hence making it closed.

Comment: Thanks, can I prove $(-\infty,1]$ closed?

Comment: Yes, you can prove it is closed. Let me edit my answer to show how.

Comment: @user467365 Are you explicitly asking how to prove that the complement is open, ie by showing that every point of $(1,\infty)$ is an interior point of the mentioned segment?

Comment: @user467365 Just a small note. The segment $(a,b)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: ok, I think there is problem in my logic: I know that, if every sequence has a convergent subsequence, that set is closed (in $\mathbb{R}$). Now take, $x_n=1-n$, $x_n\in (-\infty,1]$, but limit is not, where is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

A set is closed if its complement is open.

The complement of $$ (-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$$ is the open interval (1,2) therefore $ (-\infty, 1]\cup [2,\infty)$ is closed.

Similarly you can show that  $ (-\infty, 1]$ is closed because its complement is the open interval $(1,\infty).$

Comment: ok, I think there is problem in my logic: I know that, if every sequence has a convergent subsequence, that set is closed (in $\mathbb{R}$). Now take, $x_n=1-n$, $x_n\in (-\infty,1]$, but limit is not, where is wrong here?

Comment: The real line is closed but there are many sequences in real line  without convergent subsequences. For example, $a_n = n^2 $

Comment: Your theorem is not if and only if.

Comment: thanks!${}{}{}$